# Debugging blackberry application in eclipse "source not found" problem

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am debugging an application in Eclipse.  It works fine but at some methods, for example **enterEventDispatcher()**, it shows me source not found.  Which source files should be attached to avoid this problem? I am not getting it clearly.

Comment: You can only venture into your own source code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to debug into the RIM BB OS code.  As far as I am aware, RIM does not provide the source code for their API, so there is no source to attach.