# httpwebrequest in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am newbie to blackberry application development.
I want to make an HTTPWebRequest to my server for login process with database.
SO i am trying to do following:

conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://url.com/Login.ashx?EmailId=dummy@gmail.com&Password=dummy");
            conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            int s= conn.getResponseCode();

but when i am debugging it,i am gettin error on conn.getResponseCode() line.
and Eclipse show me following error:

**Source Not Found**

Please help me to solve this issue.
If you can suggest me any better link which explains it clear then it would be best.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching on "BlackBerry Source Not Found"?

The first try gives the answer: [Debugging blackberry application in eclipse "source not found" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949532/debugging-blackberry-application-in-eclipse-source-not-found-problem)

Comment: thanks..bt what to do on that point ??how can i see what response is coming?

Comment: log it somehow (e.g. `System.out.println()`) or use `Dialog.alert()`. You will not need debuger for this, so you'll avoid the "Source Not Found" issue.